# MongoDB: Project field to a different type

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that contains documents with string fields that sometimes contain only numerical data.  I would like to write a query that utilizes the aggregation framework to filter, project and group data, but this is failing to work as expected due to the fact that the field I would like to `$avg` is a string.  Is there any way to project a field into a different type (in this case, from string to double) ?

Comment: There's still no casting available. You'll need to convert the data in the document, or use a MapReduce.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Well that is very disappointing.  Thanks for the response!